# Can the coefficient of static friction of an object be determined by the angle at which it begins to slide on a ramp?

Tags: friction

For example, if a piece of steel began to slide on pine wood at an angle of 30 degrees, would it have a coefficient of friction of .5? (Sin (30)= .5)

Edit: The reason I used sin (30) was because if you took the initial angle of elevation and rotated the triangle so you could find the x component of the force of gravity it would be sin30 (.5) x 9.81 would give you 4.905. 4.905 x the mass of the object would find the the force being exerted on the object. If for example you had a 1kg object the wieght would be 9.81 newtons and the force being exerted on the object in the x direction would be 4.905. If you divided 4.905 (force needed to make the object slide) by 9.81 you are back at .5 again.

Comment: It is standard method for finding the coefficient of static friction which you can find details of on the Internet.  The formula that you have quoted is not correct.

Comment: The coefficient is in fact the tangent of the angle, not the sine. That wouldn't make sense anyway because you can have $\mu$ larger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $mg$ be the weight of the object.   At the angle where the object starts to slide, the static friction force, $\mu_s mgcos\theta$, is equal to the component of the weight down the ramp, $mgsin\theta$.
$$\mu_smgcos\theta=mgsin\theta$$
This gives $\mu_s=tan\theta$, regardless of the weight of the object